# Problems with post request on Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, post

I'm currently trying to update users data. So here is my html form

```
        <form (submit)="onUserUpdateSubmit()"class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="username" name="username"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit">
          <span></span>
          <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Then I created updateservice.ts where I just make post request to api as following

```
updateProfile(user){
   console.log("update profile func", user)
   let headers = new Headers();
  this.authToken = this.authService.loadToken();
  headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken)
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:17696/users/update', user, {headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

But here I got stuck cause my browser gives me errors in developer console
I tried to console.log my object with username and email and its quite alright although I get username:false. And also I console.log  my object called user but it is undefined however. 
here is profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service'
import { ValidateService } from '../../services/validate.service'
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { UpdateService } from '../../services/update.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Object;
  userToUpdate: Object;
  username: String;
  email: String;
  avatar: String;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
     private router: Router,
     private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService,
     private validateService : ValidateService,
     private updateService: UpdateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile=>{
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err=>{
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  onUserUpdateSubmit(){
    const userToUpdate ={
      username:this.username,
      email:this.email,
    }
    console.log(userToUpdate)
    //required fields
    if(!this.validateService.validateUserUpdate(userToUpdate)){
      this.flashMessage.show('Please, fill in all fields', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout:3000});
      return false;
    }

    //validate email    
    if(!this.validateService.validateEmail(userToUpdate.email)){
      this.flashMessage.show('Please, enter correct email', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout:3000});      
      return false;
    }



    this.updateService.updateProfile(userToUpdate).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log( "its from update service profilecomponent.ts")
      console.log(data)
      if(data/*.success*/){ //commented cause response doesnt have property success but still registering user without displaying the flash message
        this.flashMessage.show('You successfuly changed your info', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout:3000});
        this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
      }else{
        this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout:3000});
        this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
      }
    });
  }

}
```

[image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D54Pr.png)

Comment: Are you running with your security options disabled? Chrome often needs this.

Comment: Well, your biggest problem is that you don't set a value for `this.userToUpdate`. You log `userToUpdate`, but then attempt to use the undefined `this.userToUpdate` (which is different).

Comment: I have no clue why it is undefined. I've logged it and its not undefined but when I'm passing it is undefined . Thats weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you have two different copies of a variable with the same name and that’s what’s causing the mixup

On the beginning of your update method you’re doing

```
const userToUpdate ={
  username:this.username,
  email:this.email,
}
```

const is a block scope variable meaning you are creating a copy inside this method called userToUpdate.

The variable you are passing to the service update method is

```
this.userToUpdate
```

as you can see in your code

```
this.updateService.updateProfile(this.userToUpdate)
```

By doing this you are using the public property declared on the context of your component

So to fix your issue you have two options. Either you set the values you want to the component property by doing

```
this.userToUpdate ={
  username:this.username,
  email:this.email,
}
```

Or you pass the local userToUpdate to your service call

```
this.updateService.updateProfile(userToUpdate)
```

Comment: I’m assuming you’re still getting the error after doing the refactor I’ve suggested, right? Can you edit your question to reflect the latest state of the code?

Comment: Sure I'll do it

Comment: I've posted **UPD** version.

Comment: On my understanding this console.log inside the service update method is still saying username:false, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily related with the error but you should be using primitive version of the types (lowercase object and string) instead of the capital case version. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Comment: Did you corrected the types of the properties to use the primitive versions? I don’t know if that’s causing any unexpected behaviour and tbh I don’t see anything else wrong with your code. Maybe setup a stackblitz so we can do some testing

Comment: What is the validateUserUpdate doing? Since you’re passing the reference down and the object seems to be correct before that call and wrong afterwards I think you might be updating the object inside the method and since it’s a reference it will update the original object.

Comment: thank you. I just had missprint of '=' instead of '=='. Cheers)

Comment: Always glad to help. Don’t forget to upvote the question to flag it to others :)